# How to show that for arbitrary $x>0$, there exists a sequence of increasing rational numbers $\{a_i\}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = x$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove following result:

> **Proposition**. For arbitrary real number $x > 0$, there exists a increasing sequence of **positive** rational numbers $(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to $x$.

**Note:** I want a sequence of *positive* rationals (I didn't mention "positive" in the title because the title would become too long).

Unfortunately, I am stuck. So far I've tried $2$ appoaches:

**Approach 1.**

Since $x$ is real, by definition, one can find some sequence of rational numbers $(a_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$ which is convergent to $x$. Then I've tried to recursively define subsequence $(b_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$ such that $b_i = a_{f(i)}$, where $f(0) = \min\{n \in \mathbb N \mid a_n ≥ x/2\}$, and for all $i ≥ 1$, $f(i) = \min \{n \in \mathbb N \mid n > f(i-1) \text{ and } a_{f(i-1)} <a_n < x \}$.

This approach doesn't work for arbitrary sequence $(a_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$, unfortunately (e.g., suppose that $(a_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$ is a decreasing sequence; $f(i)$ won't be defined for all $i ≥ 0$)

**Approach 2.**

By proposition proven before (in the book I am currently studying), there must exist some rational $q$ such that $x/2 < q < x$. Now we recursively define sequence $(b_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$, such that $b_0 = q$ and $b_i = b_{i-1}+\min\{1/N \mid N \in \mathbb N^+ \text{ and } b_{i-1}+1/N < x \}$. Sequence is clearly increasing, and is also bounded by $x$. So $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n = \sup(b_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$. Now it remains to show that $x$ is also the *least upper bound* (which would let me conclude that $x = \sup(b_i)_{i=0}^{\infty} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n)$. The question is, **how can I show it**?

So I have two questions:

1. Are the approaches above salvageable? I am particularly interested in second one; if I can show that for all upper bounds $M$, $x≤M$, I can conclude the proof.
2. Are there any other approaches?

Comment: $a_{n+1}\in\Bbb Q\cap(\max(a_n,x-1/n),x)$.

Comment: To salvage Approach 2: First replace $\min$ with $\max$ in the definition of $b_i$. There is no minimum in that set. Call $N_{i-1}$ the $N$ that gives you that maximum. Note that $\frac{1}{N_{i-1}}<x-b_i\leq \frac{1}{N_{i-1}-1}$. The first inequality is the condition in the set, while the second comes from $1/N_{i-1}$ being the maximum. If the second inequality didn't hold, then you $1/(N_{i-1}-1)$ would satisfy $b_{i-1}+1/(N_{i-1}-1)<x$ and be larger. The sequence $N_{i-1}$ must tend to infinity, otherwise $b_i=b_0+\sum_{k=0}^{i}\frac{1}{N_k}$ would tend to infinity. Therefore $x-b_i\to0$.

Comment: $$\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}n=x-\frac{\{nx\}}n.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take
$$a_n = \frac{\lfloor 10^n x\rfloor}{10^n}$$

where $\lfloor . \rfloor$ denotes the integer part of a number.

Answer (score -2):

Alternate approach

Either $x$ is rational, or it isn't.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~x ~\text{is rational}}$

Define $a_n$ as $x - (1/n)$.

Clearly, each $a_n$ is (also) rational, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = x.$

Also, clearly, $a_{n+1} > a_n$.

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~x ~\text{is not rational}}$

Then, the expression of $x$ in decimal format must have an infinite number of digits after the decimal point, like $\pi$ or $\sqrt{2}$.

This is because if the expression for $x$ in decimal format
has only a finite number of digits after the decimal point, this would automatically imply that $x$ is rational, which contradicts the Case 2 assumption.

Note that the fact that some rational numbers (also) have an expression in decimal format that involves an infinite number of digits after the decimal point is irrelevant.

With $x > 0$, let the (infinite) decimal expression of $x$ be given by $K.d_1 d_2 d_3 \cdots$

Here, $K$ is a non-negative integer, and $d_1, d_2, d_3, \cdots$ are each in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,9\}$.

Take $b_n$ equal to the rational number that represents the (infinite) decimal expression of $x$, **truncated** to $n$ decimal places.

For example, if $x = \sqrt{2}$, then $b_1 = 1.4, b_2 = 1.41, \cdots.$

Again, you have that $\langle b_n\rangle$ is a sequence of rational numbers that converges to $x$.

**Problem**
In this scenario, if $d_{k+1} = 0$, then $b_{k+1} = b_k,$ which violates the constraint that $\langle b_n\rangle$ needs to be a strictly increasing sequence.

In order to salvage the approach, the sequence $\langle b_n\rangle$ will be **massaged** into the sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$ in such a way that:

- $\langle a_n\rangle$ is a strictly increasing sequence.
- Each $a_n$ is also rational.
- $\langle a_n \rangle$ also converges to $x$.

If, in the decimal expansion of $x$, decimal digit $d_n \neq 0$, then set $a_n = b_n$.

Suppose that in the decimal expansion of $x$, the decimal digits $d_{r+1}, d_{r+2}, \cdots d_s$ are all zero, $d_r$ is non-zero, and $d_{s+1}$ is non-zero.

Then $a_r$ was set to $b_r$, and $a_{s+1}$ will be set to $b_{s+1}$.  Therefore, the challenge is to construct the sequence $a_{r+1}, a_{r+2}, \cdots, a_s$ in such a way that $a_r < a_{r+1} < a_{r+2} < \cdots < a_s < a_{s+1}.$

Here, define $F = \frac{a_{s+1} - a_r}{2s+1} \implies F$ is rational.

Then, 
set $a_{r+1} = a_r + F$ 
set $a_{r+2} = a_r + 2F$ 
set $a_{r+3} = a_r + 3F$ 
$\cdots$ 
set $a_s = a_r + sF$.